# Magento edit custom attribute from user edit screen on front end

Tags: magento

I'm using this magento extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-attributes-4340.html to create customer attributes. I'm able to create the attribute and view it in the backend. But I'm unable to edit/update the values when a user logins in via the front end.

This is my code on the edit.phtml page.

```
<li><?php $attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer','height'); ?>
 <label for="height"><?=$this->__('Height') ?></label>
   <div class="input-box">
    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" />
  </div>
</li>
```

I haven't added anything manually to my database or created any modules. Strictly using this extension. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in order to save this input in to attribute what you can do is update attribute on form submit.

1) get the value of height on the page where you submit the form. e.g $height_val

2) Now $height_val has the value so you can try this code this will update the attribute's value without saving the whole product instead.

```
$customer->setHeight($height_val); 

$customer->getResource()->saveAttribute($customer, 'height');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply DepH, but i'm not dealing with products here. I'm just looking to update a registered users information. I tried what you mentioned but that didn't seem to work.